# setting up AJP secret between Apache and Tomcat

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat, ajp

I'm having trouble setting up a secret between Apache (2.4.41) and Tomcat (7.0.99). I think I have it setup correctly in Tomcat (server.xml):

```
<Connector ... secretRequired="true" secret="123" />
```

When I try to setup the Apache end (httpd-ajp.conf):

```
ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/ secret="123"
```

Apache fails to start and the Apache error log says:

```
AH00896: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

and

```
AH00957: AJP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8009
```

If it makes any difference, I'm using XAMPP for Windows 7.3.13

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mod_proxy_ajp` didn't support the `secret` option before Apache 2.5.

Please refer:

- v2.4 document: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html
- v2.5 document: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html

Comment: The docs says it is available from 2.4.42, but it is not released yet. Is there any way to know when it is supposed to be released?

Comment: It's available now. I just deployed this change to my server to add the secrets.

Comment: @KellenMurphy what is the configuration you used ? Is `ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/ secret="123"` working . my httpd fail to start with that.

Comment: @Viraj don't put quotes around the secret, i.e. `ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/ secret=123`

Comment: also there need to be a space before the secret.  However it takes you to the TC manager, how to you configure to go directly to an app as root, www.mysite.com  with /mysite on TC?